# two setTimeout functions not working separately

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My value adds 0.0150 in every 90ms and when value becomes 2.15, 0.0150 is being added in every 80ms, But I want to make two of those functions, I mean that after 3.15 I want 0.0150 to be added in every 70 and etc I wrote this function but not working any solutions ?

```js
  data:{
    crashValue: 1
  },
  mounted(){
    this.startTimer();
  },
  methods:{
    crashFunction: function() {
      this.crashValue += 0.0150;
      this.startTimer();
    },
    startTimer(){
      setTimeout(this.crashFunction, this.crashValue > 2.15 ? 80 : 90);
      setTimeout(this.crashFunction, this.crashValue > 3.15 ? 70 : 80); // When I add this it value goes up really really fast
    }
  }
```

```html
          <h2 class="crashNumber">{{ crashValue.toFixed(2) }}x</h2><br />
```

Comment: Can you give the link to some sandbox with your code to play with it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/charuashvili/pen/LYEXpPa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
startTimer () {
  let interval = 90

  if (this.crashValue > 2.15) {
    interval = 80
  }

  if (this.crashValue > 3.15) {
    interval = 70
  }

  setTimeout(this.crashFunction, interval);
}
```

In your code you're creating two timers that are running at the same time. Every time one of those timers fires it'll create another two timers, leading to an exponential growth in the number of timers running.

If I've understood correctly then you just need a single timer and a bit of suitable logic to determine the current interval.